# Use array from function directly, without assigning a variable first

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables, return-value

I'm curious if I can assign a variable the value of a specific array index value returned by a function in PHP on one line.

Right now I have a function that returns an associative array and I do what I want in two lines.

```
$var = myFunction($param1, $param2);
$var = $var['specificIndex'];
```

without adding a parameter that determines what the return type is, is there a way to do this in one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP 5.4, you can do this: `$var = myFunction(param1, param2)['specificIndex'];`.

Another option is to know the order of the array, and use [`list()`](http://php.net/list).  Note that `list` only works with numeric arrays.

For example:

```
function myFunction($a, $b){
    // CODE
    return array(12, 16);
}

list(,$b) = myFunction(1,2); // $b is now 16
```

Comment: This is a good answer.  The `list(,$b)` is probably not the best syntax to use for readability, though (in my opinion).

Comment: @user1477388: I know, but it was just an example.

Comment: Sadly my server uses PHP 5.2. thanks for the list option though

Answer (score 1):

You could add an additional optional parameter and, if set, would return that value.  See the following code:

```
function myFunction($param1, $param2, $returnVal = "")
{
    $arr = array();

    // your code here

    if ($returnVal)
    {
        return $arr[$returnval];
    }
    else
    {
        return $arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that there are better ways to solve the problem.

Comment: I'd make it a one-liner: `return ( $returnVal) ? $arr[$returnVal] : $arr;`

Comment: @FabianoLothor: Feel free to post them if you would.  @nickb:  Yes, that is also an option.  For best readability, I posted mine as a simple `if` statement.