# Access array key returned by a function

Tags: php, arrays, function

i have a function that returns an array with keys and values, like this

```
function someinfo($x, $y){

    //something done by the function
    //the array will be like

    $info=array(
        "name" => "aaa",
        "email" => "aaa@aaa.com"
    );

    return  $info;
}
```

i can do this

```
$returned_info=someinfo(1,2);
print $returned_info['name'];
```

but i want something in one line of code, like:

```
print $someinfo(1,2)['name'];
```

how can i print the values from the returned array in one single line?

thanks,
have a nice day

Comment: `print $someinfo(1,2)['name'];` available since `php5.4`. On older version use `print $returned_info['name'];`

Comment: `Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].` http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use array from function directly, without assigning a variable first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074763/use-array-from-function-directly-without-assigning-a-variable-first)

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass the `return key` like

```
function someinfo($x, $y , $key){

    $info=array(
        "name" => "aaa",
        "email" => "aaa@aaa.com"
    );
    return  $info[$key];
}
```

and print like

```
print($someinfo(1,2,'name'));
```

And **PHP 5.4.0** facilitates the this Short array syntax even

```
print $someinfo(1,2)['name'];
```

Comment: thanks, it is a good idea. i made like this - function ($x, $y, $key="") and made an if inside the function that verifies if the $key has a value or not and returns the entire array or only the key